# Decrypt MD5 hash

Tags: python, cryptography, md5, cracking

Is there any way to decrypt the encrypted [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) string, given the key?

Comment: encrypted with what? md5 is hashing, not encrypting.

Comment: MD5 hash is a one-way function.

Comment: While the premise of the question is flawed (A hash is "a one way trip" i.e. it is `not a bijective function`, and also it doesn't involve a key, only an input message) the responses go beyond stating that "this is not what a hash is for" and explore ways of finding messages that satisfy one particular hash value, and ways of protecting against `dictionary/brute-force` attacks with the use of `salt`.  Interesting !

Comment: @mjv not being bijective is not the property that makes md5 a "cryptographic hash function".
for instance f = x*x is not bijective but it is not "a one way trip" because if i said that f(x)=4 you would know that x would either be -2 or 2 that does not happen with cryptographic hashing functions.
hope i was clear ;)

Comment: Why downvote this question? Sure, he didn't understand what MD5 is in the first place, but the question is still valid.

Comment: I agree @ibz. Plus, hashing is encrypting too. The hash value is cryptographic and the correct term for this "hashing" is actually "cryptographic hashing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Google (see [Using Google To Crack MD5 Passwords](http://it.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=07/11/20/1914209)) or an online DB of MD5 hashes like [md5();](http://md5.rednoize.com/) or [GDATA](http://gdataonline.com/) (the last one contains 1,133,766,035 unique entries).

Answer (score 22):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a [one-way hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_hash). It cannot be decrypted. The closest thing to decrypting an MD5 hash would be to do a lookup against a pre-generated [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "I have the key". There is no "key" in an MD5 hash. Perhaps you are thinking of a salt? If your data has a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) value incorporated prior to hashing, the rainbow table approach probably won't be practical anyway.

Answer (score 4):

MD5 is not a encryption algorithm, it is a hashing algorithm. Read up on [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5) and [Crytographic Hash Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

To create a [MD5 hash](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) of a string in Python you do as follows:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("String to Hash")
echo m.digest()
# '\xed\xa5\x8bA-nU\xa2\xee\xbb[_s\x130\xbd'
echo m.hexdigest() # its more common to show hashes as a hex string
# 'eda58b412d6e55a2eebb5b5f731330bd'
```

Answer (score 4):

Message-Digest algorithm 5 is a widely-used cryptographic hash function with a 128-bit hash value. Encryption has 2 way : encrypt - decript, hash has one way - there is no decryption possible.
BUT with database hash **IS POSSIBLE** to solve this issue.

See this sites :

<strike>www.rednoize.com – 50,709,274 Hash in database</strike>

<strike>www.md5oogle.com – 6,353,625 Hash in database</strike>

<strike>www.hashmash.com – 1,611,191 Hash in database</strike>

<strike>www.gdataonline.com 1,155,613 Hash in database</strike>

<strike>www.md5decryption.com – 872,145 Hash in database</strike>

[www.md5decrypter.com](http://www.md5decrypter.com) – 583,441 Hash in database

<strike>www.md5decrypter.co.uk – 41,568,541 Hash in database</strike>

<strike>www.macrosoftware.ro – 5,403 Hash in database</strike>

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is an asymmetric hash -- not an encryption mechanism. You can't "decrypt" an MD5. If you know the hashed contents are limited to a (short) set of possibilities, you can use a [Rainbow Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to attempt to brute-force reverse the hash, but this will not work in the general case.