# How to decrypt MD5 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

I do this in Ruby:

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest("Jose")
```

and get "70483b6e100c9cebbffcdc62dea07eda"

But, how do I decrypt it back to "Jose"?

Comment: You can't, it wasn't encrypted to begin with, it was hashed. Hashing is 1 way. The only way to find out the value of the hash is a rainbow table.

Comment: Hashes cannot be *dehashed* because they're not being *enhashed*, just *hashed*. Otherwise it would be called *encryption*.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562064/decrypt-md5-hash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes

Answer (score 44, accepted):

MD5 is a **hashing** algorithm, you can not easily decrypt the output back to the original (and this is exactly why we use hashing algorithms).

A common example is passwords. Instead of storing a password in your database, you generate a MD5 hash of the original password and store it. If one day someone steals your database it's harder for them to figure out the real passwords, as they can not be directly decrypted.

But when you're trying to login a user, he's going to type the real password, you will then run the MD5 algorithm again and compare the hash with the one you have stored, if they're the same then the user possibly typed the correct password.

Answer (score 18):

You can't 'decrypt' it, as it was never encrypted. Trapdoor hashing algorithms may map multiple distinct strings to the same key (a 'collision'). MD5 is such an algorithm.

Consider a much simpler hashing algorithm:

```
def dumb_hash( str )
  str.each_byte.inject(0) do |hash,c| 
    ( hash + c ) % 10
  end
end

p dumb_hash( "hello world" )   #=> 6
p dumb_hash( "hi there kids" ) #=> 6
```

This algorithm produces a very large number of hash collisions, unlike MD5; but still, you can't 'decode' 6 to "hello world". The best you can do is to hash your own strings until you find one that produces the same result (and hope that this is what the original was).

…That said, however, large databases exist that have already <strike>encrypted</strike> *hashed* huge amounts of strings and associated them with their MD5 hash. For example, if you type `70483b6e100c9cebbffcdc62dea07eda` into http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/, you *do* get "Jose" back.

If you wanted to do this in Ruby, what you would do is something like the following:

```
require 'digest'
require 'sequel' # http://sequel.rubyforge.org/
DB = Sequel.sqlite 'md5s.db'
DB.create_table? :hashes do
  String :original
  String :hash
end

# Fill the DB with whatever is on each line of the file
IO.foreach( 'my_gigabytes_of_words.txt' ) do |line|
  line.chomp!
  DB[:hashes] << { original:line, hash:Digest::MD5.hexdigest(line) }
end

# Read from the DB
def find_originals( hash )
  DB[:hashes].filter( hash:hash ).map(:original)
end

p find_originals("70483b6e100c9cebbffcdc62dea07eda")
#=> ["Jose"]
#=> ...if that was in your gigabytes of source words
```

Comment: Those databases of pre-encrypted hashes are called "rainbow tables" for the curious.

Answer (score 6):

MD5 is a one-way hash encryption algorithm. There is no way to directly decrypt a MD5 hash. The algorithm itself uses modular arithmetic to package the serialized string and there is no way to go backwards from that. Think about it, if you have 6 % 4 = 2 and then you have 9 % 7 = 2 then both results end up as 2. This is kinda how md5 works.

The only way to get some form of un-encrypting a md5 digest is to compare other hashes to it. So does md5("me") == hash, then hash decrypted = "me". This form of a lookup uses a rainbow table. You may have some luck looking online for a "md5 rainbow table lookup".

Here is an example md5 lookup website:

http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/

Comment: Interesting that you explain the working of MD5 by showing a *collision*... ;)